# Is Adobe Photoshop CS3 compatible with Windows 8.1?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows-8.1

Is Adobe Photoshop CS3 compatible with Windows 8.1? I have heard that CS2 is not compatible.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "confirmation" by Adobe but please read [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4938512). Looks like it's **not compatible** as per the users that tried to install it.

Nevertheless, you can upgrade to CS5-6 with your serial number to have it installed over Windows 8/8.1

Hope this help!